# i getting error while running Android studio incompatible type databasereference required storage reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I getting error while running Android studio  incompatible type databasereference required storage reference

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Storage for Firebase are two separate products, each with their own API/SDK. You're trying to access a file in Storage, but then using the Realtime Database SDK/API to do so, which can't work.

The solution is to [create the reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/create-reference) as documented and:

```
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();

final StorageReference filePath = storageRef.child("profile pictures").child(currentUserId);
```